# Architecture of a simple JAVA EE app

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I was given the task - to create a simple JAVA EE web-application that have the following functionality:

1. It had an index page
2. I choose an algorithm and enter parameters for it on index page
3. Depending on chosen algorithm a statistical .csv file will be processed on its own way.
4. After processing the .csv file in compliance with entered parameters and chosen algorithm I get a table where I can find processed data.

I know that it's a very simple application but I don't know what to do - architecture, what kind of web layer and etc

Comment: Any EE technology will be able to handle this seemingly simple task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you install Apache Tomcat on your computer, and then run it, you will find a lot of simple examples, many of which will come close to what your are asking. Plus, once you install it, you have a server on which to run your new code. I would recommend you start there.

[Apache Tomcat](https://tomcat.apache.org/)

Answer (score 0):

I would say that if you really want simplicity, you go with just Servlets for the server-side processing, and JSP pages for the HTML views. I know, it's "vintage" almost, but will get you running in no time and without the need for any special "architecture" or framework besides the servlets API.

You can build your app as a War file with the tool of your choice and deploy it in a Tomcat server and that's it.